# How to prove that an open interval is convex.

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Hi I'm trying to prove that the interval $(a,b)$ is convex.

I know that something is said to be convex if: Let $I$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $I$ is convex if and only if for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x < y < z$ and $x \in I$ and $z \in I$ then $y \in I$.

I'm not sure though how to use this to prove $(a,b)$ is convex. Can someone give me a hint on how to start it.

Comment: This really is completely trivial; where are you stuck? Remember, $x\in(a,b)$ if and only if $a<x<b$.

Comment: You could start by writing down exactly what it means that $x\in I$ and $z\in I$, in terms of inequalities. Together with $x<y<z$ this gives you a number of inequalities. Compare those to what it means that $y\in I$, and see if you have enough to conclude that goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a,b)$ contains all points bigger than $a$ and smaller than $b$. For arbitray $x$, $y$, and $z$, can you prove using what you know of $x$, that $y$ is bigger than $a$? And using what you know of $z$ that $y$ is smaller than $b$?